# Each blocks for arbitrary nested arrays

Tags: javascript, templates, multidimensional-array, svelte

https://svelte.technology/guide#each-blocks gives an example of each blocks to output a table-like structure:

```
<div class='grid'>
  {{#each rows as row, y}}
    <div class='row'>
      {{#each columns as column, x}}
        <code class='cell'>
          {{x + 1}},{{y + 1}}:
          <strong>{{row[column]}}</strong>
        </code>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

The example requires this particular structure:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "foo": "a",
      "bar": "b",
      "baz": "c"
    },
    {
      "foo": "d",
      "bar": "e",
      "baz": "f"
    },
    {
      "foo": "g",
      "bar": "h",
      "baz": "i"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to use this feature if the columns are not known beforehand, or even more generally, if each row might have a different length?  E.g. (for the latter):

```
{
  "rows": [
    [1],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6]
  ]
}
```

I don't see anywhere indicating a syntax for `#each` that can "reach into" a component's data before iterating, as it were.

Am I missing something or is the inner loop of this impossible with `#each`?  If it is impossible, what are some other ways to do it?  (E.g. can you use a function to iterate over the inner arrays and nest a secondary template?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just learning off of the documentation here, but from what I can tell you should be able to treat `row` as a list of `cell`s:

```html
<div class='grid'>
  {{#each rows as row, y}}
    <div class='row'>
      {{#each row as cell, x}}
        <code class='cell'>
          {{x + 1}},{{y + 1}}:
          <strong>{{cell}}</strong>
        </code>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed!  See in action at https://svelte.technology/repl/?version=1.6.11&gist=d752ea8039f82f70ff490a87b90ab318 .  I'm not sure where you found that in the docs, could you point me to it?  The section I linked to doesn't have much detail, so to me the fact that you can use either something from your data array, or something from the current context, without specifying which, is a bit...magic-y.  :)

Comment: I did not actually pull that specific text from the docs; I just inferred that `#each list as item` might create a variable `item` and from my knowledge in other languages I hoped that this `item` could be iterated as well. By "learning off the documentation" I meant that I had zero prior experience with Svelte before attempting to answer this question... just to let you know in case I made a novice mistake. But I'm glad the advice helped! :)